# UIActionSheet display from Toolbar

Tags: iphone

Have two issues one is `showFromToolbar` statement format warning issue and another is that in performAction method how i can display `UIActionSheet`.

`ActionSheet` from `showFromToolbar` `UIBarButtonItem`

when i use this statement

```
[ActionSheet showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar *)view];
```

On analyzing it shows warning for expected expression

```
UIActionSheet *ActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                             initWithTitle:@"Language Options"
                             delegate:nil
                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:@"Devanagari", @"English", nil];

ActionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;

[ActionSheet showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar *)view];

[ActionSheet release];
```

Button which displays ActionSheet

```
UIButton *pagecurlButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[pagecurlButton addTarget:self action:@selector(performAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

pagecurlButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.1, 0.1, 30, 30);

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pagecurl.png"];

[pagecurlButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *pagecurl = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:pagecurlButton];
```

In performAction method how i can display actionsheet upon hiiting.

```
-(void)performAction:(id)sender
```

Comment: is the app targeted for iPad?

Comment: you need to pass in a UIToolbar instance or use a different method, maybe `[ActionSheet showInView:sender];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand why you do **this:**

```
[ActionSheet showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar *)view];
```

It doesn't make any sense. If you want to present an `UIActionSheet`, you have to do this from a real view. You have five methods to do this:

```
– showFromTabBar:
– showFromToolbar:
– showInView:
– showFromBarButtonItem:animated:
– showFromRect:inView:animated:
```

In your case I would recommend using the third one - `showInView:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[actionSheet2 showFromToolbar:(UIToolbar *)self.view];
```